# text-shadow does not appear Nuxt

Tags: css, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I have this default layout:

```
<template>
    <div class=" bg-primary h-screen">
        <div class="flex justify-between text-primary flex-col bg-secondary lg:flex-row">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
                <nuxt-link to="/"><h2>1x1 Photos</h2></nuxt-link>
                <button v-if="!showMenu" @click="() => { showMenu = true }" class="btn">Menu</button>

            </div>
            
            <ul v-if="showMenu" class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row">
                <button v-if="showMenu" @click="() => { showMenu = false }" class="btn lg:invisible">Hide Menu</button>
                <li class="btn">
                    <nuxt-link to="/">Collections</nuxt-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
        <div class="text-secondary p-4 flex flex-col items-center text-center">
            <slot />
        </div>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    const showMenu = ref(false);
    if (process.client) {
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        if (width > 1024) {
            showMenu.value = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
.btn {
    @apply px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-xl font-semibold m-4;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), -1px -1px 4px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    
}
.btn:hover {
    @apply bg-primary backlit;
}

.backlit {
    @apply text-white;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(242, 235, 235, 0.70);
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    @apply font-bold p-4;
}
h1 {
    @apply text-4xl;
}
h2 {
    @apply text-2xl;
}
h3 {
    @apply text-xl;
}

</style>
```

However, the `text-shadow` in `backlit` does not show up. I know that tailwind doesn't support `text-shadow`, but that is why I created my own css class and did not add the shadow using `@apply`. However, it still doesn't show up. The text is white, so I know that the class is at least applied.
This is what it should look like:
[image]

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. As [per the CSS specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor/#text-shadow-property), the syntax is:

```
<color>? && <length>{2,3}
```

Which means an optional color and 2 or 3 lengths. Compare this with your value which has 4 lengths. Consider removing one of the lengths according to your desired visual presentation:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.incorrect {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(242, 235, 235, 0.70);
}

.corrected {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(242, 235, 235, 0.70);
}
```

```html
<div class="incorrect">Incorrect</div>
<div class="corrected">Corrected</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure why Figma is giving me incorrect code! This worked perfectly.